# Java JTree freezing when file is re-selected

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree that I use as a file tree. If I choose a new file, and select the same one as was already selected, the tree freezes up for some reason. It should be removing the old JScrollPane containing the tree and replacing it with a new one, and it works fine if I select a different file, but not with the same one. The rest of the GUI still works, it's just the tree that freezes. Here is the relevant code:

```
if ("browse".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(DSAuto.this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            filename = file.getAbsolutePath();
            l1.setText("Job Location: " + filename);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.weightx = 1.0;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridwidth = 10;
            c.gridheight = 9;
            c.ipady = 0;
            if (rm)
                pane.remove(ft1);
            else
                pane.remove(sp1);
            if (rm2) {
                pane.remove(l3);
                rm2 = false;
            }
            if (!(file.isDirectory() || file.isFile())) {
                l3 = new JLabel("404 File Not Found");
                pane.add(l3, c);
                rm2 = true;
            } else {
                ft1 = new FileTree(file);
                ft1.all = allB;
                pane.add(ft1, c);
                rm = true;
            }
        }

    }
```

I can supply the code for the FileTree class, as well, if that is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It should be removing the old frame and replacing it with a new one

You can't add/remove a JFrame from a JFrame so I don't know what that comment means.

Don't remove/add components? If you want to update an existing component then change the model. That is:

```
tree.setModel(...);
```

Or if you do remove/add components, then you need to use:

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized after I posted that I had said frame instead of pane. You must have replied before I edited it. I've never seen that setModel() before. Okay, adding revalidate and repaint made it work. I'll learn how to use setModel so I can do that next time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SaintWacko, `It should be removing the old JScrollPane containing the tree and replacing it with a new one`. In this case you do not need to replace the scrollPane. Instead you use `scrollPane.setViewportView(tree)`. Rarely do you ever need to remove/add new components.

Comment: Well, the thing with that is that the scrollPane is actually part of FileTree class. It just made more sense to do it that way, as a file tree really wouldn't be much use outside of a scroll pane. I'll remember that setViewportView for the future, though.